# Manipulate existing Leaflet map in a shiny app with javascript using shinyjs

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet, shinyjs

I have a shiny app with an existing leaflet map in it. I want to be able to manipulate this map after rendering, using custom javascript through the `shinyjs` package. A minimal example is below:

**app.R**

```
# packages ----------------------------------------------------------------

library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# ui ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(script = "my_js.js"),

  leafletOutput(outputId = "map", height = "80vh"),

  tags$hr(),
  tags$p("Button to run the JS code"),
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Add a Marker")

)

# server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session){

  # define a simple map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")
  })

  # observe the go button and run the shinyjs.addMarker function
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$go,
    handlerExpr = js$addMarker()
  )

}

# run ---------------------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**my_js.js**

```
shinyjs.addMarker = function(){

  // get the map - this bit doesn't work!
  var map = document.getElementById('map');

  // create a marker and add to map
  var marker = new L.marker([53, -1]).addTo(map);

  // really I'd be going off and querying an API, or doing
  // something else for which there is no handy R function.

};
```

The question really is how to access the map object after it has been created. Obviously with this example I'm just adding a marker, which I could do with `leafletProxy()`, but in reality I want to query an API and bring extra data onto the map when the user performs an action.

Any help or advice on other ways to do this would be appreciated!

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reach the map object with `htmlwidtget`'s `onRender()` function. Then, you might save it to the globally scoped variable (by skipping the `var` keyword while creating the variable). This becomes available anywhere in the JavaScript code.

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
        htmlwidgets::onRender("
            function(el,x) {
                map = this;
            }
        ")
})
```

Your my_js.js would then look as follows:

```
shinyjs.addMarker = function(){

  // create a marker and add to map
  var marker = new L.marker([53, -1]).addTo(map);

  // really I'd be going off and querying an API, or doing
  // something else for which there is no handy R function.

};
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for this answer. This is useful to know but doesn't quite answer my question as it doesn't let me manipulate the map *after* rendering, but *on* rendering (as the function name suggests!). I can't I tie it to an `observeEvent()` or similar, without re-rendering the whole map. I think the only "proper" way of doing what I want is to write a `leaflet` extension, after the fashion of the 'easyButton' and 'miniMap' extensions already available.

Comment: Hi! I updated the answer to meet your needs. If you apply that, the observeEvent works as expected.

Comment: Oh now that is very nice - basically using the `onRender` to add a hook? Thank you!